# hide child element with dynamic bootstrap table

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, parent-child

I'm using a dynamic table example I found [here](http://www.bootply.com/GGAMvot45f#) (bootply). Its basically a table with a parent, child relationship, so you can click on a row and it will drop down another row. I added one more level to this example, so you can think of this example as a parent, child, grandchild relationship. My issue is that if you go two levels deep, and then click the parent row it only hides the child row, but not the grandchild rows. I need to fix this 'bug' somehow.. I've tried wrapping the parent row in a div and using href="#collapse1" and than putting that id on the grandchild row but that doesn't work. Any other suggestions are greatly appreciated.  Here's the html..

```
<table class="table table-responsive table-hover">
  <thead>
        <tr><th>Column</th><th>Column</th><th>Column</th><th>Column</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="clickable" data-toggle="collapse" id="row1" data-target=".row1">
            <td><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>  
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="collapse row1">
            <td>- child row</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>  
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="clickable collapse row1" data-toggle="collapse" id="row3" data-target=".row3">
            <td>- child row</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>  
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="collapse row3">
        <td>- grandchild row</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>  
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="clickable" data-toggle="collapse" id="row2" data-target=".row2">
            <td><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>  
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="collapse row2">
            <td>- child row</td>
            <td>data 2</td>
            <td>data 2</td>  
            <td>data 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="collapse row2">
            <td>- child row</td>
            <td>data 2</td>
            <td>data 2</td>  
            <td>data 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Doesn't work with a fiddle.js for some reason.. but if you go to the link and copy&paste this code you can replicate the issue.

Comment: Can you add your JS code?

Comment: Could you post your example with script on JSFiddle, so someone can track the bug?

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work on fiddle.js, I wanted to post a fiddle... if you go to the link and paste the code it replicates the issue I'm having

Comment: @Cory The only JS used for this example comes from the bootstrap.js file itself.  The original poster uses no additional JS.

Comment: exactly why I didn't post any extra JS..

Comment: I assumed he'd have some for what is being attempted--it will require so. You'll probably need to give the grandchild a class and then add the `collapse in` class on click event. But what that looks like will depend greatly on whether or not the structure of each collapse is static - i.e. will there always one parent, two children and one grandchild?

Comment: there is a one to many relationship with the parent and child and another one to many relationship with the child and the grandchild.. thats what makes this difficult.. any example of this 'collapse in' would be great because I haven't worked with it before. Thanks